# How can I alter SQL Prompt settings to not auto-correct a phrase?

Tags: sql, sql-server, red-gate-sql-prompt

I have SQL Server Mgt Studio, and have the red-gate SQL Prompt plugin. For most cases, it's amazing and makes life easier with most auto-corrects, but I'm using a specific database called offset, but it'll always auto-correct it to OFFSET because it's a function in SQL.

How can I disable the auto-correct on a case-by-case basis? I'm assuming it's somewhere in the options setting, but cannot find where. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hit ESC to close the window when done typing the word before hitting space, but if you hit ESC after 'fo' and then type 'o' it will kick in again.

Another option if you don't use it often would be to disable it (Tools->Options->Text Editor->Transact-SQL->General->Auto list members) and use CTRL+J to bring it up manually when you want to use it. Red Gate also has a product called SQL Prompt which might offer more control.

In addition there is an "Intellisense Enabled" option under the Query menu and on the Query toolbar if you want to temporarily disable/enable it.

Source: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20068/suppress-sql-server-management-studio-auto-complete

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Hit ESC to close the window when done typing the word before hitting space.

Another option if you don't use it often would be to disable it (Tools->Options->Text Editor->Transact-SQL->General->Auto list members) and use CTRL+J to bring it up manually when you want to use it.

In addition there is an "Intellisense Enabled" option under the Query menu and on the Query toolbar if you want to temporarily disable/enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in mysql community edition. It autocorrects the keywords like text to TEXT and value to VALUE. I use Accute or back quotes symbol ( `text` ) . This works for me.